# How to Loop initial conditions to solve a coupled differential equation using nested for?

Tags: differential-equations, procedural-programming

I need to solve the following pair of coupled differential equations and find the plots for the ground state radial wave function, the potential and the energy eigenvalue for the ground state.
$$V''(r) + \frac{2}{r}V'(r)=R^2(r) $$
$$ \frac{1}{2}[R''(r) + \frac{2}{r}R'(r)]- V(r)R(r)= - ER(r) $$
The paper that I am referring (Click [here][1] for the paper) two boundry conditions as given by:
$V'(0)=0$ and $R'(0)=0$. following this, the paper says that we are supposed to search for the correct value of $R(0)$ and $V(0)$ with both the functions vanishing at infinity.

I tried to construct nested for loops in order to achieve this but the program continued to execute for a very long time. This is the code that I used:

```
For[i = 0.00001, i <= 0.3, i += 0.00001, 
 For[n = 0.00001, n <= 0.3, n += 0.0001,
  For[k = 0.00001, k <= 0.3, k += 0.0001,
   s = NDSolve[{-i* R[x] - R[x] V[x] + 
        1/2 ((2 Derivative[1][R][x])/x + (R^\[Prime]\[Prime])[x]) == 
       0, -R[x]^2 + (2 V[x])/r + (V^\[Prime]\[Prime])[x] == 0, 
      Derivative[1][R][0.00001] == 0, Derivative[1][V][0.00001] == 0, 
      R[0.00001] == n, V[0.00001] == -k, 
      WhenEvent[
       DirichletCondition[R[x] == 0, True], {"StopIntegration"}]}, {R,
       V}, {x, 0.00001, 100}]]]]
```

When I execute this code, there is no output that I receive and Mathematica shows "Running" at the top. Is there a better way to do this or is my way of doing it completely wrong? Any help in this regard is greatly appreciated.

1]: https://www.researchgate.net/publication/13277564_Gravitational_atoms_Gravitational_radiation_from_excited_boson_stars/link/53f1f4aa0cf272810e4c79cc/download

Comment: You are asking it to do perhaps as many as .3/0.00001*.3/0.0001*.3/0.0001=2.7*10^11 `NDSolve` and you are puzzled why it doesn't immediately respond with a solution?!?! Just as an experiment, increase your step size by 100x or more in each of those loops. That will mean you are only asking it to do 2.7*10^5 `or less NDSolve` and see if you get an approximate solution after lots of hours or a few days.

Comment: Just as an experiment, time how long it takes to do `NDSolve` for a few hundred different random values of i,n,k and see if those times are roughly all the same. (But I fear that some values might take WILDLY longer than others and that would wildly skew the total time) Then multiply a conservative estimate of the time by 2.7*10^11 and let us know what that number is. I'm curious.

Comment: @Bill I'm aware that the number of computations I'm wanting Mathematica to perform are very high, which is why I'm convinced that a different method needs to be employed in solving this particular problem. However, I don't know what that other method is.